# Hide/show textboxes with jQuery based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, radio-button

I need for certain textboxes to show up when a certain radio button is clicked on my form, otherwise the textboxes should remain hidden. Here's an example of what I have:

HTML:

```
Radio buttons:
<p>Show textboxes<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show" onClick="getResults()">Do nothing<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Nothing"></p>
Textboxes:
<div class="text"><p>Textbox #1 <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30"></p></div>
<div class="text"><p>Textbox #2 <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30"></p></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide()
    function getResults() {
        $(".text").show()
    };
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/)

When I take out the .show() code, the textboxes stay hidden. I need to show them when a radio button with the onClick event gets selected. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/technologrich/tT48f/4/)

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $("#r1").click(function () {
        $(".text").show();
    });
    $("#r2").click(function () {
        $(".text").hide();
    });
});
```

Html

```
<p>Show textboxes
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r1" value="Show">Do nothing
    <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="r2" value="Nothing">
</p>Wonderful textboxes:
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #1
        <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
<div class="text">
    <p>Textbox #2
        <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is simple to understand and works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inline `onclick()` javascript, you can use `.click()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').eq(0).click(function() {
        $(".text").show()
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/2/)**

However, you should use `.change()` event for the `input` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".text").hide();
    $('input[type="radio"]').eq(0).change(function() {
        $(".text").show()
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide()
    $('[name=radio1]').on('change', function(){
        $('.text').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
    })
});
```

Inline event are not recomanded, so bind a change event the the radio and if the value is `Show`, well show it!

http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/3/

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can pass the clicked object as `this` in form of parameter to `getResults()`, Where `this` refers to the current clicked object

See below

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide()

});
function getResults(elem) {
    elem.checked && elem.value == "Show" ? $(".text").show() : $(".text").hide();
};
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show" onClick="getResults(this)">
Do nothing                                                         ^^^^
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Nothing" onclick="getResults(this)">
                                                                      ^^^^
```

Fiddle `-->`    http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/7/

Answer (score 2):

Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/9/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".text").hide()
    $('[name=radio1]').on('change', function(){
        $('.text').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Redefine a little bit your HTML markup and then you could only use CSS:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tT48f/8/)

```
input[value=Nothing]:checked ~ .text{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide();

});

function getResults() {
        $(".text").show();
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. $("input[name='Radio1']").change(function(){
           if($(this).val()=="Ya") {
                $("#QUESTION_1").fadeIn(250);
           }
           else {
               $("#QUESTION_1").fadeOut(250); 
           }        });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
                        <div class="RdoClick">
                            <asp:RadioButton ID="RadioSugges" runat="server" GroupName="PopupRadio" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;C. Insert your suggestion:" />
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="PopupTxtBox" PlaceHolder="Enter your suggestion..."
                            onClick="check();" TabIndex="1" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
        document.getElementById('<%=RadioSugges.ClientID%>').checked = true;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When answering question pay attention to code formatting. Also try to avoid code only answers.